# Cant write to network shared disk in macOS Big Sur (only sudo)

Tags: big-sur, nfs

I mounted network nfs shared folder in terminal with `mount -v -o vers=4 -t nfs IP_ADDRESS:/ /Users/USERNAME/shared`, I see network location in Finder with right content of shared folder, But i cant write to it (copy/move my files).

I can read anything but write work only in terminal in sudo mode.

I think it is some permission problem, but i cant figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of investigating I found working solutions, I had to change a server export setings to

```
no_subtree_check,no_auth_nlm,insecure,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000,all_squash,rw
```

Also I had to change mount options in mac terminal

```
mount -v -w -o vers=4,noowners,rw,nolocks,locallocks -t nfs IP_ADDRESS:/ /Users/USERNAME/shared
```

Now it looks like everything works well.